# Shouldn't 'equities' be singular here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> Another way to come up with ex ante arguments is to imagine how a
>   legislature would think about the problem facing the court. Legislatures
>   make general rules for the future; they don’t resolve individual disputes
>   that have already occurred. So if a legislative committee or a government
>   agency were considering a rule about how banks should handle hostage
>   takers, it less likely would be distracted by the **equities** of any one case.
>   Its role would be to make decisions that have consequences ex ante—going
>   forward.

Source: p 6, The Legal Analyst, Ward Farnsworth

The plural definition [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equity?q=equities#equity__7) is 2.1, but which doesn't make sense in this context. Since that (independent) clause is discussing "any one case", shouldn't it use the singular of Definition 1 (= The quality of being fair and impartial) ? One case can't be equitable in different ways, then it's not equity?

Comment: Even though a particular case is singular, it may have multiple conditions that must each be evaluated for fairness or impartiality.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the abstract, general meaning of **equity** as a virtue, etc. you are correct. However I believe this is a legal term that can be pluralized: **an equitable right or claim**:

See definition [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/equities)

Answer (score 1):

I did find a definition of "equities" that would be plural in context (there might be several claims or overlapping rights):

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/equities

*4. law: an equitable right or claim: equity of redemption*

It seems to me that the word "facts" would be better in context (or maybe "particulars"), and either would be plural. I think you have found an example of a poor word selection.